# while accessing textfield in a dynamic cell I have an error

Tags: swift, uitableview, error-handling

When I try to access a textfield I added as an outlet to my custom tableviewcell class, I got an error.
    customerCell.textField.placeholder = "Name"

The error is "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". I don't understand why I am getting nil

Comment: where you are facing it in your project ?

Answer (score 1):

This could occur because the textField you are accessing is `nil`. Use unwrapping like this:

```swift
customerCell.textField?.placeholder = "Name"
```

This is a fix for the crash, but still, the placeholder won't be set. For that you need to make sure the @IBOutlet os connected if done via storyboard.